# Pinging namecheap.com resolves to localhost, except from Ubuntu in WSL

Tags: networking, dns, ping, domain

I hope this is the right place to ask this question, if you know of a more approriate place please let me know and I'll move my question there.

I kept getting connection refused when trying to access namecheap.com, I started troubleshooting when I noticed that pinging namecheap.com resolved to pinging 127.0.0.1, the only ways I can actually see namecheap's real IP and to view the homepage's content is to ping/curl from Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux, or going through a proxy.

The problem occurs pretty much with any other device (laptop, pc, phone) or network (wifi, mobile).

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Daniel - What DNS provider are you using?  Instead of submitting a temporary comment, edit your question, to include any and all vital information.  Comments are designed to be temporary, any existing comments, are likely to be deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, I actually fixed the issue forcing Windows to use google's dns server, I didn't even know that was an option, what's should I do now? edit my question with the solution or give an answer to my own question? Thanks.

Comment: Please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparenty there was something wrong with my DNS provider, when using nslookup all I got was "DNS request timed out".

I fixed the issue by forcing Windows to use Google's DNS server, with the following steps:

- control panel
- network and internet
- network status and tasks
- change adapter settings (top left)
- < current connection > right click, properties
- select Internet Protocol Version 4, click properties
- Tick "Use the following DNS server addresses" and specify 8.8.8.8

nslookup now works as expected and I can finally load namecheap.com.
I'm guessing the same will apply to my phone, which is most likely using the same problematic DNS server.